Cannot catch error when using Model.findOne
I want to fetch a user by email using async/await, if not found I want an error to be thrown.
If the email exists I do get the correct user returned, however if the email is not correct I get: Could not get response and Error: read ECONNRESET in Postman
How do I catch the error?
router.post("/login", async function (req, res) {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email }).orFail();
        res.send(user);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send("error", error);
    }
});


It looks like you're using orFail() to throw an error if the user is not found, which is a good practice. By default orFail() throws DocumentNotFoundError. To catch and handle the error properly, you can modify your code to send a more informative error message and status code if the user is not found:
router.post("/login", async function (req, res) {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email }).orFail();
        res.send(user);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === 'DocumentNotFoundError') {
            res.status(404).send("User not found");
        } else {
            res.status(500).send("Internal server error");
        }
    }
});

In the above code, if the error thrown is a DocumentNotFoundError (which is the error type thrown by orFail() when the document is not found), the response will have a status code of 404 and a message "User not found". Otherwise, a generic internal server error message with a status code of 500 will be sent.
Another way you can use orFail is by passing the desired error as argument,
router.post("/login", async function (req, res) {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email }).orFail(new Error('User not found');
        res.send(user);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send("error", error.toString());
    }
});

However, if you don't want to get into such detailing the easiest solution would be not to use orFail(), but check for null document returned as below,
router.post("/login", async function (req, res) {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
          res.status(404).send("error", "User not found");
        }

        res.send(user);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send("error", error.toString());
    }
});

For more info: read about orFail here

You can try that:
  const user = await Users.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) {
    res.status(404).send("error", "User Not found");
  }


Simply query for the user, and check if it is null.
     const user = await User.findOne({ email });
       if (!user) {
          res.status(404).json({message: 'User not found'})
       }  

       res.status(200).json(user)

